# Capture repeating pattern in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am having a string which is having repeating patterns but not sure how many they are. I want to grep these using regex

For example:

I am having following string

```
str = "var1 123 var2 234 key sdrfw3 current junk varn adads"
match = re.search("(\w*)\s*(\w*)", str)
print match.group(1), match.group(2)
```

Problem is I am not sure how many key values will come in this string but all will follow same pattern. How to grep key and value

Comment: You may use `re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+(\w+)', s)`.

Comment: Are the "variables" always named `var + number`? If not, how can you distinguish them from "current junk"? What rules can be used to differentiate "junk" from variables?

Comment: Thing is all are space separated. there is no fix pattern for keys and values